# Unable to build CMake project in MingW, wrong library path

Tags: cmake, build, linker, mingw

I'm trying to build a CMake project (which uses OpenMP as a dependency) in using the MingW command line, but I'm running into strange linker errors:

```
/cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libgomp.a: Invalid argument
/cannot find -lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libmingwthread.a: Invalid argument
```

which I suspect is caused by invalid library path (the shell is running from C:/msys64). I've confirmed that both libraries exist within `C:/msys64/mingw64/lib`, and have tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to that directory, but compilation keeps failing.
Is there any alternative way to set the proper library paths? The project buids just fine in Linux.

Comment: how exactly are you depending on OpenMP? Show us a [mre].

Comment: It's not my project, it's a [library available in a public repository](https://github.com/CMA-ES/libcmaes/) (hence why how it's declaring the dependency in OpenMP is redundant, the issue is clearly in MingW and not the source code)

Comment: "wrong library path" - This is wrong description of the problem. The error message tells `Invalid argument`. That is, your linker doesn't accept `-l` option at all or (more likely) the driver specification is incorrect. You need to provide **more details** about how do you configure the project. Also, add to the question post the output from CMake, where it prints which exact compilers are used and other relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

`-lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libgomp.a` and `-lC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libmingwthread.a` really are **Invalid arguments**.

The linker should be called with either the path to the library files:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libgomp.a C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libmingwthread.a
```

or with proper linker flags:

```
-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgomp -lmingwthread
```

If you use CMake you need to fix how these libraries are being linked.

Comment: This was my feeling as well, but I'm still not sure if it can be solved in MingW configuration, or just by editing 'CMakeLists.txt' directly?

Comment: You will need to edit `CMakeLists.txt`. Maybe you should add the part of it that specifies this linking information.

Comment: Where exactly do I edit [libcmaes's CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CMA-ES/libcmaes/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)? There no explicit statement linking to those libraries.

Comment: Where did libcmaes get into the picture?

Comment: `libcmaes` is the project I'm trying to build (as I've written in the comments to the question)

Comment: libcmaes builds fine under my MSYS2 shell environment with MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ which provides gomp and threads

Comment: I've only been able to build the static library, if building a shared library I get the error above. I am trying from MSYS2 shell using the bundled CMake configuration (and MingW's g++ compiler), perhaps I do need winlibs?

Comment: Do you also have shared eigen library?